# cast varchar to integer in teradata

Tags: casting, integer, varchar, teradata

I have a column which is defined as varchar(19). So it can have alpha-numeric values.I have cast it to integer. Simple casting will give overflow exception and if I am tring to format it as Z(9) or '999999999'  it shows error saying column has combination of  numeric, character  and GRAPHIC values

I have another casting too for which the column is defined as decimal(13,3) and I need to convert it to integer..I am clue less here too.

Any ideas guys??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VARCHAR(19) would exceed the upper boundary of the INTEGER data type in Teradata.

Try BIGINT or DECIMAL(19,0) instead.